# I am trying to get a .ItemSource Return JSON Object for a listview

Tags: rest, listview, xamarin, cross-platform

I did find a solutions to my main problem which was using REST to fill a listview with data.  The sample I found had a returned of a JSON array.  While testing, there was an error telling me I needed a JSON Object verses a JSON Array. I confirmed this by looking at the data in the was returned in Fiddler.   With that information I found some code to convert the response to a JSON Object from a recent post. Upon re-writing the table class and changing all the code I am stuck in understanding the Return object of the function.  When it was a JSON Array the Return was return rootoject.Users;  In my case in following the same syntax it should be rootobject.Office;.

This is the call from the portable class:

```
var sv = new RestClient();

List.ItemsSource = await sv.getOfficeAsync();
```

This is the JSON Object data table class:

```
public class OffcObjecct
{
    [JsonProperty("TableName")]
    public Office[] office { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OfficeName")]
    public string officename { get; set; }
}
```

This is the RESTClient class with the JSON deserialization of the response and my return object in question:

```
    public RestClient()
    {
    }

    public async Task<Office[]> getOfficeAsync()
    //public async Task<OffcJason> GetOffcAsync()  
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var uri = "https://application.azurewebsites.net/tables/Tablename?$filter=(field%20eq%20" + Vars.Number + "M)";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", SessVars.strAuthToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var offcsJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OffcObjecct>>(offcsJson);

        return rootobject.office;

    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v8RP.png)

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

```
// root object will be a List<OffcObjecct>
var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OffcObjecct>>(offcsJson);
```

each item in this `List` is a `OffcObjecct` that contains a property `office` which returns a `Office[]`

I have no idea why you've chosen to structure your data this way - but if you want to return a Office[], which is what your method signature requires, try

```
return rootobject[0].office;
```

Comment: I was on the right path but until I saw your response I didn't put it together.  You mention; why did I choose to structure the data this way.  I am completely new to REST and Jason.  I am putting the pieces together as I go.  Would you share how you would structure the data?  I assume you are talking about the "public class Office".